# Codeigniter - Default template's PHP code is not executed

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates

I have moved my codeigniter site to Amazon EC2 server. All of a sudden, it stoped working I fount that the template (php) is treated as HTML and not PHP. Hence variables & functions in template are not executed.

```
<link href="/<?php=$this->config->item('url_suffix')?>css/sliders.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/<?php=$this->config->item('url_suffix')?>css/buttons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/<?php=$this->config->item('url_suffix')?>js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/<?php=$this->config->item('url_suffix')?>js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/<?php=$this->config->item('url_suffix')?>js/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/<?php=$this->config->item('url_suffix')?>js/js.slide.js"></script>
```

This is what I get in the browser

Answer (score 1):

Write echo before config item

```
<?php echo $this->config->item('url_suffix') ?>
```

instead of

```
<?php=$this->config->item('url_suffix')?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This didnt work. CI treats the template as Just HTML and not as PHP. So no code in template works

Answer (score 1):

You can also try and go for an alternative syntax :

```
  <?php echo base_url();?>resources/js/filename.js
```

Same goes for CSS

I also did something. I made a global helper file and added the following in it :

```
function load_js($js_file=NULL,$tag=true)
{
if($js_file!=NULL){
    if(file_exists("./resources/js/".$js_file))
        return '<script type="text/javascript" src="'.base_url()."resources/js/".$js_file.'"></script>';
}
}

function load_css($css_file=NULL)
{
if($css_file!=NULL){
    if(file_exists("./resources/css/".$css_file))
        return '<link  type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="'.base_url()."resources/css/".$css_file.'" />';
}
}
```

And I use them in my code by doing the following :

```
<?php echo load_js('filename.js'); ?>
<?php echo load_js('filename.js'); ?>
```

Try one of these and reply if the problem persists.